# Need to change the mount Point of LVM /u001/app/oracle to /u001/

Tags: rhel, mount, lvm

This is the situation.I installed the RHEL 5.5 on client's system and created LVM mount point at /u001/app/oracle and now he has installed DB on /u001/app/oracle. He is asked me to change the mount point of Existing LVM /u001/app/oracle to /u001/.

And preserve the directories /app/oracle in /u001/.

Problem is this if i change the mount point of LVM from /u001/app/oracle/ to /u001/ it will delete the directories /app/oracle and database will not be able to identify the NEW URL.

Now this is what i need

Change the mount point of /u001/app/oracle to /u001/ and preserve the /app/oracle/ directories (These two shouldn't be deleted after changing the mount point because these are the part of URL database is using)

Directory Structure

```
FileSystem                            Size     Used     Mounted on 
/dev/sda1                             100G     21G      /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00       450G     83G      /u001/app/oracle
/dev/sda2                             487M     13M      /boot
```

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with? The second part of point 2. needs a bit more explaining or is irrelevant. (I really hope you've got good, valid backups that you know how to restore for that/those database(s).)

Comment: in second part, Will the size of LVM after changing the Mount point of LVM /u001/app/oracle to /u001/ **remains the same which is 450GB right now**.

Comment: And Do you know how to change the mount Point of LVM from /u001/app/oracle to /u001/ while keeping the directories /app/oracle in /u001/ intact

Comment: Again, what problem do you have with that? It's just a matter of remounting & moving the stuff to the appropriate place afterwards. The shrinking the filesystem part is much more risky. Given that you can't seem to figure out the first part on your own, I'd really suggest you find a different way of doing all that (namely creating a new 200G filesystem and doing a simple copy to that & remount.)

Comment: You didn't get it. There is a database on /u001/app/oracle and i can't move it so I have to keep it intact after remounting lvm from /u001/app/oracle/ to /u001/. Man just tell me how to do that. Waiting .....

Comment: I know exactly what you're trying to do. And 1. is very easy and **requires** moving stuff. What's I'm trying to say not too harshly is that if you can't figure this out yourself, you should be handing the task to someone more senior before you trash your customer's database.

Comment: Unfortunately Senior Admin left. So there is no other option. Ok tell me what steps are required. And im not disrespecting you Sorry for my harsh reply Hahahahha. This is the replication of Live env Means is a Test system. So no need to worry. If every thing will be ok then i will move on to perform the steps on Live system. Thanks man waiting for reply

Comment: MODS kindly move it to Super User Forum only if permissible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a mount hierarchy like this:

```
/dev/hd1   /
/dev/hd2   /a/b/c
```

And want to change it to

```
/dev/hd1
/dev/hd2   /a
```

while preserving the structure of the `/a` directory as seen by applications, and **assuming that `/a` and `/a/b` are otherwise empty**, the transformation is simple:

- stop the database (and everything that depends on it)
- make sure you have a valid (restorable) backup of everything
- take note of the permissions on directories `/a`, `/a/b` and `/a/b/c`
- unmount `/a/b/c`
- update your `fstab` (or whatever your OS uses) to reflect the new layour
- mount `/a`

Then:

- `mkdir -p /a/b/c`
- restore the permissions on those directories as they were before
- move everything in `/a` to `/a/b/c` (except `b` you just created obviously).

---

Example/simulation:

```
$ ls /u001/app/oracle
admin/
diag/
product/
...
# umount /u001/app/oracle
# <edit fstab>
# mount /u001
$ ls /u001
admin/
diag/
product/
...
```

At this point, your Oracle files are "re-rooted" at `/u001`. You just need to move them to the right hierarchy

```
# mkdir -p /u001/app/oracle
# check & adapt the permissions on those directories, making sure they
# are identical to what you had
$ mv /u001/* /u001/app/oracle
<warning about not moving app to a subdirectory of itself - ok>
# Don't forget the .dotfiles
$ mv /u001/.??* /u001/app/oracle
```

Comment: Sorry dear for very late reply from my part.I was out of the city. Ok i will test this soon and will let you know. Thanks man